# Why strptime c-function changes the structure?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, strptime, time.h

Incomprehensible behavior of the function `strptime()`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double getPeriod(char * dateStart, char * dateStop) {
    struct tm tmStart, tmStop;
    time_t timeStampStart, timeStampStop;

    strptime(dateStart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tmStart);
    strptime(dateStop, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tmStop);

    timeStampStart = mktime(&tmStart);
    timeStampStop = mktime(&tmStop);

    printf("%d\t%d\n", tmStart.tm_hour, tmStop.tm_hour);
}

int main()
{
    getPeriod("2016-12-05 18:14:35", "2016-12-05 18:18:34");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
17  18
```

Why does this happen?

Compiler gcc (GCC) 6.2.1
OS Linux

Comment: You need to initialize the `tm_isdst` member of `timeStampStart` and `timeStampStop` to -1.

Comment: [Seems to work on GCC and Clang here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b54f234cc33eb6c)

Comment: @user4815162342: Oh man, that daylight savings time thing is always such a pain! And I think you meant for `tmStart` and `tmStop`

Comment: This is my output screen: [link](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=fe6b82d83bf07875952d6af6a072a476)

Comment: `mktime()`, needs to have all fields (expect `tm_yday` and `tm_wday` initialized. There are at _least_ 7 other fields, `tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday, tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec` **and** `tm_isdst`.  Recommend `struct tm tmStart = { 0 };`.  Some implementations have other fields.  Uncertain if these other fields apply to gcc.

Comment: Yes, thank you, its work

Comment: There is no C++ in this code, so it should not be tagged C++.

Comment: @chux Others will be initialized by `strptime`. Still, initializing the whole struct is good practice. `tm_isdst` should probably be set to -1 and not to zero (unless one really means to specify DST as not in effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmStart` and `tmStop` are not initialized, so some fields will be uninitialized when passed to `mktime`. Thus, the behavior is technically undefined.

From the [`strptime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) man page (note the first two sentences):

> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but only stores the values specified. This means that `tm` should be initialized before the call. Details differ a bit between different UNIX systems. The `glibc` implementation does not touch those fields which are not explicitly specified, except that it recomputes the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` field if any of the year, month, or day elements changed.